# How to get embedded signing URL for a recipient who doesn't have email and name

Tags: docusignapi

My use case is, create an envelope with an agent to specify the following signer's name and email.

I created the envelop by POST `{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes`, with request body:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "agents": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1",
        "email": "aaa@example.com.au",
        "name": "Agent",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ],
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "2",
        "email": "",
        "name": "",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
              "anchorString": "Signature_anchor_1",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "name": "Please sign here",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "{{fileName}}",
      "documentBase64": "{{fileBase64}}"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

After the agent specify the name and email address of the signer, I could not obtain the signing URL by POST `{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient` , with request body:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "2",
  "userName": "",
  "email": "",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "returnUrl": "https://www.sample.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email"
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
    "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A value was not found for parameter 'userName'."
}
```

I tried to get it with the new specified name and email:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "2",
  "userName": "new",
  "email": "new@example",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "returnUrl": "https://www.sample.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email"
}
```

But still got the error response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

I tried to get the `recipientId` by calling the get envelop API and use the `recipientId` to retrieve the view but still not working.

How can this URL be generated? What request body should it be?

---

Update:
With scenario below:

1. Envelope has 1 Agent and 1 Recipient, when the sender sends out the envelop, the email and name of the recipient are unknown for the sender, only agent knows the info (that's why I put the name and email as empty for the recipient).
2. Agent received the request and put in the name and email address for that recipient
3. We want to get that embedded signing link for the recipient, but now seems that we could not retrieve it even with the info obtained by calling GET `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

---

Update 2:

As suggested to put a place holder for the name and email and also add the clientUserId for the signer, I call the create envelope API with request body:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "agents": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1",
        "email": "aaa@example.com.au",
        "name": "Agent",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ],
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "name": "example",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
              "anchorString": "Signature_anchor_1",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "name": "Please sign here",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "{{fileName}}",
      "documentBase64": "{{fileBase64}}"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

For the agent, he cannot change the email/name for the signer, since when he accesses the DocuSign signing link, DocuSign pops a message "**All recipients have been assigned**".

So I tried to use `intermediaries` instead of `agents` and call with the request body:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "intermediaries": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1",
        "email": "aaa@example.com.au",
        "name": "Intermediary",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ],
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "name": "example",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
              "anchorString": "Signature_anchor_1",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "name": "Please sign here",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "{{fileName}}",
      "documentBase64": "{{fileBase64}}"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

The intermediary can update the name/email for the signer. But after the intermediary change the info, DocuSign will send an email to the updated email address even the `clientUserId` is already set in the request body for that signer.

I'm wondering if this is the expected behaviour:

1. Whenever an intermediary updates a signer's name/email, DocuSign will send the email to the updated email address regardless whether the `clientUserId` is set for that signer

This might be another question, but it seems DocuSign handles the update email event for signer and witness differently. I'm wondering scenario I observed is the expected one:

1. When a signer updates/adds the name/email for his witness, DocuSign will not send the email to the updated email address if the `clientUserId` is set for that witness

---

Update3:

After calling with the `intermediaries` param, I can retrieve the Signer's signing URL by either calling with request body:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "2",
  "userName": "example",
  "email": "example@example.com",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "returnUrl": "https://www.google.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "clientUserId": "2",
  "userId": {{userId retrieved from get envelope recipients}},
  "recipientId": "2",
  "returnUrl": "https://www.google.com",
  "authenticationMethod": "email"
}
```

**But after the intermediary changed the email/name of the recipient, none of the above request body could retrieve the signing URL.** I tried both original and updated `clientId` and (`email` + `name`) combination, but still not working.

I assume this is a design of DocuSign: it's not allowed to retrieve the recipient's signing URL after an intermediary changes the recipient'e email/name, this signing URL can be only obtained by that email sent by DocuSign. This email cannot be turned off event the `clientUserId` is set. Is it correct?

---

**Update 4:**
As suggested, I tried with the `workflow` option with request body:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "intermediaries": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1",
        "email": "aaa@example.com.au",
        "name": "Intermediary",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ],
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "2",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "name": "example",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
              "anchorString": "Signature_anchor_1",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "0",
              "name": "Please sign here",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "workflow": {
    "workflowSteps": [
      {
        "action": "pause_before",
        "itemId": "2",
        "triggerOnItem": "routing_order"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "{{fileName}}",
      "documentBase64": "{{fileBase64}}"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I can only pause the workflow before routing order 2, since there would be a 400 error if I put the `workflow` param as to achieve "*insert a workflow pause immediately after the intermediaterecipient*":

```
  "workflow": {
    "workflowSteps": [
      {
        "action": "pause_after",
        "itemId": "1",
        "triggerOnItem": "routing_order"
      }
    ]
  },
```

After the intermediate recipient updated the name/email, I did an API call to set the `clientUserId` for the signer and it works fine. But I was not able to resume the workflow by calling URL `{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}?resend_envelope=true` with request body:

```
{
    "workflow": {
        "workflowStatus": "in_progress"
    }
}
```

The status of the signer stayed as `created` and could not be updated to `sent`, thus could not retrieve the signing URL for the signer. How can we unpause the workflow?

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU!

Comment: Please ask your question about unpausing a workflow as a new stackoverflow question. StackOverflow is not designed for more than a very direct back and forth. Issues about the workflow are a different question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

today every recipient in DocuSign must have an email and name. I suspect for legal reasons requiring a name would always be enforced.
In your scenario, there's an name and an email, you just don't know what they are, right?
You can first do a GET recipients call on this envelope
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Then you'll get the email an name and you can make the POST call to generate the embedded signing URL.

Comment: Maybe I'll explain the scenario in more detail.

Comment: 1. Envelope has 1 Agent and 1 Recipient, when the sender sends out the envelop, the email and name of the recipient are unknown for the sender, only agent knows the info (that's why I put the name and email as empty for the recipient). 2. Agent received the request and put in the name and email address for that recipient 3. We want to get that embedded signing link for the recipient, but now seems that we could not retrieve it even with the info obtained by calling `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`.

Comment: And after the Agent fill in the name and email for the Recipient, Docusign automatically sent out an email for that Recipient. I'm wondering whether this email can be turned off?

Comment: @YungangFeng -- please ADD the additional information to your question by EDITing your question. Don't try to put this kind of info as a comment.

Comment: You can try to add a clientUserId to the recipient. I'm not 100% sure if that would work with added recipients, but worth a try. clientUserId being set suppresses the email going out.

Answer (score 0):

> After the Agent fill in the name and email for the Recipient, Docusign automatically sent out an email for that Recipient. I'm wondering whether this email can be turned off?

Much better would be to give the agent an application that lets them set the name/email of the recipient. The application would also set the client_user_id attribute so emails are not sent.

> Is a name and email required?
> Yes, but if you don't know the person's email (and you are using embedded signing) then you can make up an email that includes the signer's name and uses the `example.com` domain since that domain does not exist. Eg If the signer is Pat Johnson then use patjohnson@example.com as the email address.

Also remember that if you don't have the signer's email address, then you probably (discuss with your legal counsel) need some way for the signer to obtain a copy of what they signed. Normally DocuSign does this by sending to the person's email. But if you know that the email is fake, you'll need a different plan.

### Update

I believe that when the `intermediary` recipient sets the name/email of the signer, the signer's attributes, including the client_user_id are being reset. So the signer receives the invite email since they're (at this point) a regular signer.

One fix is to insert a [workflow pause](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/pause-unpause-workflow) immediately after the intermediaterecipient. Then use that pause to change the signer to have a client_user_id.

Comment: I've updated my findings to the question based on your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Larry K , I've updated the findings in the question based on your suggestion of using workflow pause, but still got some problems.